# Vectorizing a loop through lines of data frame R while accessing multiple variables the dataframe

Tags: r, date, vectorization, apply

Yet another `apply` question.

I've reviewed a lot of documentation on the `apply` family of functions in R (and use them quite a bit in my work).  I've defined a function `myfun` below which I want to apply to every row of the dataframe `inc`.  I think I need some variant of `apply(inc,1,myfun)`  I've played around with it for a while, but still can't quite get it.  I've included a loop which achieves exactly what I want to do... it's just super slow and inefficient on my real data which is considerably larger than the sample data I've included here.

I expect it's a quick fix, but I can't quite put my finger on it... maybe something with special argument `...` to apply?

English version of what the code below does: I want to look at all the Submit Dates in the `inc` dataframe and find for each of these dates, how many rows in `chg` there are where `chg$Submit.Date` is within some range of the `inc$Submit.Date`.  Where the range is controlled by `fdays` and `bdays` in `myfun`

### setting up some fake data

```
chgdf <- data.frame(Submit.Date=as.Date(c("2013-09-27", "2013-09-4", "2013-08-01", "2013-06-24", '2013-05-29', '2013-08-20')), ID=c('001', '001', '001', '001', '001', '005'), stringsAsFactors=F)
incdf <- data.frame(Submit.Date=as.Date(c("2013-10-19", "2013-09-14", "2013-08-22", '2013-08-20')), ID=c('001', '001', '002', '006'), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

### the function i want to apply to every line of the data frame inc

```
myfun <- function(tdate, aid, chg=chgdf, inc=incdf, fdays=30, bdays=30) {
  fdays <- tdate+fdays
  bdays <- tdate-bdays
  chg2 <- chg[chg$ID==aid & chg$Submit.Date<fdays & chg$Submit.Date>bdays, ]
  ret <- nrow(chg2)
  return(ret)
}
```

## works for one line of inc dataframe

```
tdate <- inc[inc$ID==aid, 'Submit.Date'][1]
myfun(tdate, aid='001', bdays=50, fdays=100)
```

### works but slow...with full dataset

```
inc$chgw <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(inc)){
  aid <- inc$ID[i]
  tdate <- inc$Submit.Date[i]
  inc$chgw[i] <- myfun(tdate, aid, bdays=50, fdays=100)
}
```

Comment: Doubt that the example works since `tdate` is a string and you use it like a number inside `myfun`

Comment: See, also, `mapply` (or its equivalent `Vectorize`): `Vectorize(myfun)(incdf$Submit.Date, incdf$ID, bdays = 50, fdays = 100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you call `apply` all values are coerced to strings, so you need to convert `tdate` before using it. Otherwise you're trying to add days to a string:

```
tdate <- as.Date(tdate)
fdays <- tdate+fdays
bdays <- tdate-bdays
```

Second, you call `apply(inc, 1, myfun)`. Note that in that case you're passing a single parameter to `myfun` (the whole row), and not several parameters as `myfun` is supposed to receive.

**Solution 1:** Change your function to receive a whole row of the dataframe and call as you did:

```
myfun <- function(row, chg=chgdf, inc=incdf, fdays=30, bdays=30) {
  tdate <- as.Date(row[1])
  fdays <- tdate+fdays
  bdays <- tdate-bdays
  chgdf2 <- chgdf[chgdf$ID==row[2] & chgdf$Submit.Date<fdays & chgdf$Submit.Date>bdays, ]
  ret <- nrow(chgdf2)
  return(ret)
}
> apply(inc, 1, myfun)
[1] 1 2 0 0
```

**Solution 2:** Call `apply` using all parameters in the function call:

```
myfun <- function(tdate, aid, chg=chgdf, inc=incdf, fdays=30, bdays=30) {
  fdays <- tdate+fdays
  bdays <- tdate-bdays
  chgdf2 <- chgdf[chgdf$ID==aid & chgdf$Submit.Date<fdays & chgdf$Submit.Date>bdays, ]
  ret <- nrow(chgdf2)
  return(ret)
}
> apply(inc, 1, function(row) myfun(as.Date(row[1]), row[2]))
[1] 1 2 0 0
```

I personally prefer the second solution, because it gives you the possibility to change the default values of your other parameters in `myfun`:

```
> apply(inc, 1, function(row) myfun(as.Date(row[1]), row[2], bdays=50, fdays=50))
[1] 2 3 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Julian's answer:

```
sapply(
  split(incdf, 1:nrow(incdf)), 
  function(x) do.call(myfun, c(unname(x), bdays=50, fdays=100))
)
```

Here I don't use `apply` because `apply` will coerce the whole row to the same type, which may not be desirable.  Note we need to `unname(x)` because your df doesn't have the same column names as args to your function.