# Optimizing a vectorized function using apply, compiler, or other techniques

Tags: r, function, optimization, dataframe, apply

I'm seeking to optimize this algorithm `smartWindow` and (and the process where I original post which explains some context around the function and how I got here:
[Vectorizing a loop through lines of data frame R while accessing multiple variables the dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050554/vectorizing-a-loop-through-lines-of-data-frame-r-while-accessing-multiple-variab)).

This currently takes me 240 seconds to run on my actual data.  I've tried some `Rprof` It seems that `chg2 <-` line of smartWindow is eating the most time. I've also tried the compiler in R using `cmpfun`  I'm wondering there's a way to significantly improve the speed of what I'm trying to do.

What I'm really looking for, is if there's a technique to accomplish what I've done below in something closer to 20 seconds than 240 seconds. I've shaved off 1-5% of of the computation time using various things. but what I'm really wondering is if I can decrease the time by a factor of a number greater than 2.

```
## the function
smartWindow <- function(tdate, aid, chgdf, datev='Submit.Date', assetv='Asset.ID', fdays=30, bdays=30) {
  fdays <- tdate+fdays
  bdays <- tdate-bdays
  chg2 <- chgdf[chgdf[,assetv]==aid & chgdf[,datev]<fdays & chgdf[,datev]>bdays, ]
  ret <- nrow(chg2)
  return(ret)
}

## set up some data #################################################

dates <- seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'), as.Date('2013-12-31'), by='days')
aids <- paste(rep(letters[1:26], 3), 1:3, sep='')
n <- 3000
inc <- data.frame(
  Submit.Date = sample(dates, n, replace=T),
  Asset.ID = sample(aids, n, replace=T))
chg <- data.frame(
  Submit.Date = sample(dates, n, replace=T),
  Asset.ID = sample(aids, n, replace=T))

## applying function to just one incident ###########################

smartWindow(inc$Submit.Date[1], inc$Asset.ID[1], chgdf=chg, bdays=100)

## applying to every incident... this is process i seek to optimize #########

system.time({
  inc$chg_b30 <- apply(inc[,c('Submit.Date', 'Asset.ID')], 1, function(row) smartWindow(as.Date(row[1]), row[2], chgdf=chg,
                                                                                        datev='Submit.Date', assetv='Asset.ID', bdays=30, fdays=0))
})
table(inc$chg_b30)
```

Comment: have you looked at the xts package? it seems to have the functionality you need, built-in.

Comment: what you want looks like a window join is it ? what you do is very slow try the data.table package first. Also please show some data input and output so we can understand what you want to do

Comment: I agree with the advice offered. However, the line you identified as slow is slow because you use data.frame features. You pay for the bells and whistles of that data structure with slow assignment and subsetting. I don't see a reason to use data.frame subsetting here. You should see a speed-up if you try something like `ret <- sum(chgdf[[assetv]]==aid & chgdf[[datev]]<fdays & chgdf[[datev]]>brays)`.

Comment: @Roland - bypassing the creation of data.frame and summing the Trues cut the time in half. thanks, good tip!